# Python - How to end a socket using a "with as" block

Tags: python, sockets, with-statement

I'm learning about sockets and connections and trying to write a simple server Python script that echos a message to a client.
I began with just running a script that prints what it receives from a socket.
So i'm running what i wrote locally and using Putty as a client (so the message  isn't printed to the putty session yet).

This is my code:

```python
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))  # bind accepts a tuple of a hostname or address and a port
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()   # returns a pair
    with conn:
        print("Connection started!", conn, addr)
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        while data:
            data = data.decode("UTF-8")
            print(data)
            # if data == "exit":
            #     shutdown and close the connection,
            #     and ofcourse exit the two with as blocks gracefully   
            data = conn.recv(1024)
print("Connection is closed and the program continued")
```

Running this works but i have no way of terminating the connection other then killing the server. 
I believe that data **will always be true** since i'm using putty and it seems that even when i'm hitting enter with no text to the connection window, it actually sends this:

```
b'\r\n'
```

So I tried placing this inside the commented if statement:

```
conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
conn.close()
```

Hoping this will just make the socket be deleted - but it didn't work.

So what I want to do is to exit the with blocks and deleting the sockets without having to raise any exceptions or make the program stop. I tried doing so using python 3 change to socket that made it usable with with-as statements. I tried just calling the conn.__exit__ or s.__exit__ function but that didn't work also.

How can I close the socket and exit the two with blocks using an input from the user? Is there anything i'm confusing with the socket module here?

Comment: You are using sockets wrongly. TCP is a stream protocol. You have to built your own message based protocol on top of it.

Comment: Never used the socket module but wouldn't it be s.close() rather than conn.close()

Comment: `conn.recv` is blocking. If the client closes the connection, `data` becomes `None` and your while-loop terminates. Why not just close your client?

Comment: If you want to exit the loop, a `break` statement is probably the way to go. Once the loop ends, the `with` statements will clean up the sockets.